# Trying to convert columns from multiple dataframes with the same name into a new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know how I can get all the columns with the same name from multiple dataframes into one dataframe. I have created the following code:

```
import pandas as pd 

names = ['John', 'Ben', 'Carl', 'Frank']

name = {}
name2 = {}
name3 = {}
name4 = {}

for n in names:
    temp = {}
    temp2 = {}
    temp3 = {}
    temp4 = {}
    
    temp.update({'Year' : '31/12/2016', 'expl' : '123', 'expl2' : '456'})
    temp2.update({'Year' : '31/12/2017', 'expl' : '123'})
    temp3.update({'Year' : '31/12/2018', 'expl' : '123'})
    temp4.update({'Year' : '31/12/2019', 'expl' : '123', 'expl4' : '789'})
    
    name[n] = temp
    name2[n] = temp2
    name3[n] = temp3
    name4[n] = temp4
    
df = pd.DataFrame(name)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(name2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(name3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(name4)
```

So now every name is grouped per year but I want to group them by name.

[image: this is the output from the dataframes.]

So I thought if I run a loop over each column with the first name and then merge them together. Then run a loop over the second name and merge those together. Etc. This is what I did:

```
for n in names:
    df_0 = pd.DataFrame()
    df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
    df_2 = pd.DataFrame()
    df_3 = pd.DataFrame()
    
    df_0 = df.update(df.loc[:n])
    df_1 = df2.update(df2.loc[:n])
    df_2 = df3.update(df3.loc[:n])
    df_3 = df4.update(df4.loc[:n])
```

This returns `None` four times.
The result should be something like this:

```
        John
Year    31/12/2016    31/12/2017    31/12/2018    31/12/2019
expl    123           123           123           123
expl2   456           NaN           NaN           NaN
expl4   NaN           NaN           NaN           789
```

And then for the other names the same.

Comment: try this, ```pd.concat([df, df2, df3, df4], axis=1)```

Comment: I have tried it and it concatenated them all together which is a great step in the right direction. Now I only need to find a way to sort them by column name. If you have suggestions how to go about that would be great but thank you very much for you answer